# I would like to create a single supe VM (as much processors as possible) by Openstack environment

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-horizon, openstack-heat

I have deployed 2 identical compute nodes in Openstack environment (Mitaka).

Each Compute node has 2 Physical CPU, 12 Cores each.

I would like to create a single VM which has have much processors as possible.

I don't want to oversubscribe between pCPU to vCPU, i.e. I would keep physical to virtual as 1:1 ratio.

However, it seems only allow me max. to create 24 vCPU in single VM even I have 48 vCPU in my resource pool (sum up by 2 compute nodes, each contribute 24 vCPU).

Anyone have an idea how to create more vCPU in my case?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create an instance that spans multiple compute nodes with OpenStack ... or with any open-source virtualization platform that I am aware of.

The proprietary vSMP product (vendor ScaleMP) can do this and there may be other products.

The other approach that you could take is to build a cluster consisting of multiple instances, and use a batch scheduler and / or  some kind of message passing framework to perform computations spanning the cluster.

Comment: It is great! thank you for your information. You're so kind!